# Loading Laravel styles and JS from Vite on DigitalOcean

Tags: laravel, vite, digital-ocean, web-hosting, laravel-9

I am deploying a *Laravel* application on an IAAS (*DigitalOcean*), and I have already installed and configured everything. Everything is working except for the default Laravel styles (Bootstrap). As a result, I have a page without styles, but it functions normally.

- I am using Laravel 9 with Vite.
- I have already run "npm run build".

PLEASE What should I do to make it work?

[image: laravel without style]